# Limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{1^x+2^x+3^x+...n^x}{n}\right)^{\dfrac{a}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, exponential-sum

Find $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{1^x+2^x+3^x+...n^x}{n}\right)^{\dfrac{a}{x}}$$

I do not know where to start or where to end. I have never seen something like this before. Any help or hint is much appreciated!

Comment: Usually the first step is to guess what the limit should look like, by throwing away terms that are too small to matter. Here, $1^x \ll 2^x \ll ... \ll n^x$ for large $x$, so we should throw these small terms away and expect the whole thing to be roughly $(n^x/n)^{a/x} = n^{\frac{(x-1)a}{x}}$, which for large x is roughly $n^a$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ denote the argument of the limit.

The following inequalities trivially hold:
$$
\left(\frac{n^x}{n}\right)^{a/x} \leq f(x) \leq
\left(\frac{n \cdot n^x}{n}\right)^{a/x}.
$$
Hence
$$
(n^a)^{(x-1)/x} \leq f(x) \leq n^a,
$$
so that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = n^a$ by comparison.

Comment: Why do these inequalities hold? Am I missing something?

Comment: The first inequality: $1^x + 2^x + 3^x + \cdots + n^x \geq n^x$. The second inequality: $1^x + 2^x + 3^x + \cdots + n^x \leq n^x + n^x + n^x + \cdots + n^x = n \cdot n^x$.

Answer (score 3):

The first inequality holds since

$f(x) = (\frac{1^n+2^n+...+n^x}{n})^{a/x}$
$= (\frac{1^n+2^n+...(n-1)^x}{n} + \frac{n^x}{n})^{a/x} \geq (\frac{n^x}{n})^{a/x}$

Comment: I am really sorry! I checked and it is $...n^x$ instead of $...+n^x$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us set
$$
f(x)=\left(\frac{1+2^x+\ldots+n^x}{n}\right)^{a/x}\,.
$$
Taking the logarithm,
$$
\log f(x)= \frac{a}{x}\log\left(\frac{1+2^x+\ldots+n^x}{n}\right)
$$
which, as $x\to\infty$ is of the type $\infty/\infty$. Then, applying l'Hospital's rule, we have
$$
a\,\frac{2^x\log2+3^x\log3+\ldots+n^x\log n}{1+2^x+\ldots+n^x}=a \frac{(2/n)^x\log2+(3/n)^x\log3+\ldots\log n}{(1/n)^x+(2/n)^x+\ldots+1}
$$
whose limit as $x\to\infty$ is $a\log n$. Therefore $f(x)$ tends to $n^a$ as $x\to\infty$.